# Displaying a specific number over several figures

Tags: linux, bash

How can I display a number on a higher figure length? 
Here is a little script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Increment until proper folder name is found

VarAdd=0
VarDate=$( date +%F )

mkdir -v 2016-01-26-00{0..9}        # Testing script

if [ -d /.../"$VarDate-00$VarAdd" ]; then
    while [ -d /.../"$VarDate-00$VarAdd" ]; do
        (( VarAdd++ ))
    done
    mkdir -v "$VarDate-00$VarAdd"
fi
```

My problem is that at the 11th loop, the next created folder will be 2016-01-26-0010. How can I make it displayed like 2016-01-26-010?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `printf` with padding to format the string:

```
$ echo $(printf '%s-%04d' 2016-01-26 9)
2016-01-26-0009

$ echo $(printf '%s-%04d' 2016-01-26 11)
2016-01-26-0011

$ echo $(printf '%s-%04d' 2016-01-26 111)
2016-01-26-0111
```

Comment: Thanks Jim. Just a little question: what does the %s do in this? I dont find it in the man printf pages.

Comment: @Benoît: `%` is the start of a "format directive" for printf in most languages. Bash generally uses the same flags and specifiers as C printf.

Comment: Greatly appreciated. My question is answered!

Comment: @JimB May I ask what is the use of `echo` and `$( ... )`here? It seems to me that a single `\n` at the end of the first argument to `printf` is enough to get the same result. Am I missing something ?